# Is it possible to change the value of a variable in SSIS package using Script Task?

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to change the value of a variable in SSIS package using Script Task? I have a foreach loop container that does not want to read int variable, but I'm using that variable in Script Task and it needs to be int for the task I'm trying to accomplish. Every time I run the code I get the error: "Error: The type of the value (String) being assigned to variable "User::empid" differs from the current variable type (Int32). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object." Is anyone familiar with an error like this one?

```
     public void Main()
    {


        string filename;
        // string datepart;
        //bool FolderExistFlg;

        //filename = Dts.Variables["User::name"].Value.ToString();
        filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Dts.Variables["User::name"].Value.ToString());
        // datepart = (filename.Substring(filename.Length - 12)).Substring(0, 8);


        string getEmployerId = filename.Split('_')[0];
        int employerId = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(getEmployerId, @"\d+").Value);


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        Dts.Variables["User::empId"].Value = employerId;











    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: can you share the script details? `User::empid` is a `int32` type, if you are using `C#`, should assign `int32` data to it, or `int`, not string value like `"sample"`

Comment: I just posted the code I have together with a question. I could assign the value of the variable to an Object, but the problem is that I'm calling this variable once again in Derived Column in Data Flow Task and it does not support Object.

Comment: I don't believe that the code you have posted produces the error message in your question.   Probably that error was produced by an older version of your code.

Comment: does this parse? Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(getEmployerId, @"\d+").Value);